# How to resolve pom.xml conflicts when downmerging/upmerging changes in between different branches?

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml, artifactory

Consider this example:
Assume that I have a "develop" branch. I create a new branch out of "develop" named "XYZ". I will use "XYZ" branch for a developing a particular feature for a month.

After a month, I want to merge the entire "XYZ" branch in "develop". However, I may end up with lot of conflicts in pom.xml files of both projects. What is the best way to manage this scenario?

Note: My real problem consists of having multiple maven projects with "develop" and respective "XYZ" branches. All the projects are interrelated. Different projects will publish a "release" jar at different time intervals. Everytime a jar is released, its version will be incremented by 1 in the pom.xml. Hence, I will have to deal with multiple pom.xml conflict resolutions when I decide to merge the 2 branches.

Please suggest how I can tackle this problem. Thanks!

Comment: There is one thing in your approach. You should synchronize from master/trunk on a regular basis to your dev branch and should reduce the life time of a branch....Furthermore if so much things are changed in your pom files it sounds there is something going wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to manage it, quite simply, is to dont worry about it too much and presume that most of the merge conflicts will be non-conflicting.

The conflicting merges that come up - just handle these manually.

Generally, the work you are doing on the feature branch shouldnt conflict too much with the work that is going on in the development branch.

By the way you should look at a branching model by Vincent Driessen.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Thanks @vikingsteve